# Scrolling in UICollectionView with Compositional Layout and multiple sections without recalculating width of previous cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am trying to make a collectionview where all cells know their own width and combined give the total width of a section. Thereafter I need to be able to scroll horizontally and vertically in all visual sections at the same time.

I have managed to get the sections rendered with the correct width by overriding `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` in the cells. If I put `section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous` I can even scroll correctly horizontally pr section. The problem happens when I add multiple sections and want to scroll in the collectionview. It's as though it recalculates the width of the cells that are no longer on the screen to be of the estimated size instead of the calculated size and the everything jumps around.

[image: Jumps around gif]

Compositional Layout:

```swift
        // Item
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(10), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        //        let spacing = NSCollectionLayoutSpacing.fixed(2)
        //        item.edgeSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutEdgeSpacing(leading: spacing, top: spacing, trailing: spacing, bottom: spacing)
        
        // Group
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(2000), heightDimension: .absolute(50))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        
        // Section
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
```

Datasource:

```swift
extension SomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        dataSource[section].valueModels.count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        3
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        
        cell.setupCell(viewModel: dataSource[indexPath.section].valueModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to get this smooth?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I am sorry, I ended up giving the task to another at my company as I stopped, so I don't know how it ended.